# how to change the color of the border using hostlistener and hostbinding?

Tags: angular

I am having 3 div tags and on one of them, I have assigned the click event. My requirement is that when I click on the div element, the background color and border must change to red.

Right now when I am clicking on the div tag, the border color is changing, but not of the div element but of input element defined on the same page.
How to fix it? my code:

image.html

```
<input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" placeholder="Upload file" >
<img  id="blah" [src]="url" alt="your image" cdkDrag/>



<div class="box1" (click)="changeColor()" >
    hi
</div>

<div class="box2" >
    hi
</div>
<div class="box3" >
    hi
</div>
```

and image.ts

```
@HostBinding('style.border') border: string;
  @HostListener('click')resetColor(){
    this.border=' 5px solid red'
  }
```

Comment: Can u provide demo code on https://stackblitz.com/. It would be a quick fix then

Comment: i am not able to do so due to some tech issue with me.Can you help

Comment: i think you need whole page border red and background also red.is my understanding correct?

Comment: i only need red for the div tag in which the image will be dropped

Comment: you can use ngStyle for your requirement.And  you need to set image within div tag.

Answer (score 1):

in html:

```
<input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" placeholder="Upload file" >
<div [ngStyle]="{ 'border' : (isclicked == true) ? '5px solid red' : 'none' }"
>
  <img  id="blah" [src]="'https://pluralsight2.imgix.net/paths/images/angular-14a0f6532f.png'" alt="your image" cdkDrag/>
  </div>

<div class="box1" (click)="changeColor()" >
    hi
</div>

<div class="box2" >
    hi
</div>
<div class="box3" >
    hi
</div>
```

in ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular 4";
  isclicked = false;
  changeColor() {
    this.isclicked = !this.isclicked;
    console.log(this.isclicked);
  }
}
```

are you expect this behaviour?